# Selecting value using HQL based on a key of a Map

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have following JPA mapping.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "transaction")
    public class Transaction {

        @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "trx_addi_info")
        private Map additionalInfo;


    }
```

I want to write HQL to fetch all the transactions which has particular key-value pair in the additionalInfo map. I think I have to do a join like follows,

```
    SELECT trx FROM Transaction trx inner join trx.additionalInfo addInfo WHERE addInfo.????
```

But I'm not clear how to put the WHERE clause to get match with particular key-value pair in additionalInfo map. Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HQL `index()` specific function, that applies to aliases of a joined indexed collection (arrays, lists, and maps). See section [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) of the Hibernate reference documentation

```
//Example of HQL returning `Transaction` object that have `additianlInfo` with   
//the `KEY` equal to the string `test`

SELECT trx FROM Transaction trx inner join trx.additionalInfo addInfo WHERE index(addInfo) > 'test'
```